# RoR Rake migration doesn't succeed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake

I'm trying to do a rake db:migrate on RoR. However after running the command I get the following error (I've included trace as well). Can you please tell me how it can be soled? I have tried to rollback and repeat the procedure but it's not working.... :

```
Malions-MacBook-Air:omrails malionhoxhallari$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20141128222329 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:334:in `block in execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:334:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:457:in `add_column'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:490:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/code/omrails/db/migrate/20141128222329_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:349:in `change_table'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/code/omrails/db/migrate/20141128222329_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:990:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `block in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:156:in `invoke_task'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:121:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `block in run'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `run'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:334:in `block in execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:334:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:457:in `add_column'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:490:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/code/omrails/db/migrate/20141128222329_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:349:in `change_table'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/code/omrails/db/migrate/20141128222329_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:990:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `block in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:156:in `invoke_task'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:121:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `block in run'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `run'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:334:in `block in execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:334:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:457:in `add_column'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:490:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/code/omrails/db/migrate/20141128222329_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:349:in `change_table'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/code/omrails/db/migrate/20141128222329_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:990:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `block in migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:156:in `invoke_task'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `each'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:121:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `block in run'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `run'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/malionhoxhallari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. For a question like this, you'll probably get more/better answers with a little more context. Is this the first migration? Does the database already exist? What do your `schema.rb` and migration look like?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. I have no schema.db file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all the steps in the Devise readme(https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)?

Make sure you ran:

```
rails g devise:install
```

and

```
rails g devise User
```

before migrating.

Since the first part of the trace shows: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users so the first thing I would do is check the migration file and schema.rb to see if you've created the users table properly.

Here's an example of a working schema.rb and migration using Devise:

schema.rb:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "role"
end
```

Corresponding migration to update schema:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table(:users) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
  t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false 
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at


  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
end
end
```

Comment: Hi. What if I don't have a schema.rb file? I deleted the files manually a couple of hours ago...

Comment: @user3768997 it doesn't matter. That file has nothing to do with your error. Dallison was suggesting to check it to see whether your table exists as that file gets updated when migrating. You can regenerate it using `rake db:schema:dump`. However the more direct approach is simply to look inside the db itself. You could be missing a migration somewhere, or perhaps you accidentally deleted the table.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...the migration file will be generated before the schema (a migration updates your schema.rb file, as a side note, NEVER edit your schema.rb). Usually rails g devise User creates the migration file, then running rake db:migrate should run successfully.

Comment: Hi. the only line inside schema.rb is the following: 
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) 

end

Shouldn't schema.db be updated after running migrate?

Comment: It will be if the migration works. Something is preventing the migration from working. Did you run rails g devise Users? What steps did you take to create the users table?